# How to display nested JSON in sap.m Table (SAPUI5) for each listItem

Tags: json, data-binding, nested, sapui5

I have a sap.m splitApp where i have an overview of courses. By displaying a course you get detail information like the list of participants for that course. Currently it is only possible to display the participants of the same (one) course for all courses. How can i display the appropriate participants for each course.

If anyone has an idea that would be great :) Thanks.

This is my "Details.view"

```
sap.ui.jsview("tem_trainer.Details", {

    /** Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
    * In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
    * @memberOf tem_trainer.Details
    */ 
    getControllerName : function() {
        return "tem_trainer.Details";
    },


    onBeforeFirstShow: function(oEvent){
        this.getController().onBeforeFirstShow(oEvent);
    },




    /** Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
    * Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away. 
    * @memberOf tem_trainer.Details
    */ 
    createContent : function(oController) {



        function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
              // Discard the time and time-zone information.
              var utc1 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());
              var utc2 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());

              return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        }



        var oTimestamp = new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({

            text: '{start} - {end}, {starttime} - {endtime}',

        });

        var oRoom = new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({

            text: "{room}",


        });

        var oHeader = new sap.m.ObjectHeader({

            title: "{name}",
            number: "{start}",
            numberUnit: "Start Date",
            attributes: [
                         oTimestamp, oRoom

                         ]




        });


        var oTable = new sap.m.Table("idRandomDataTable", {
            headerToolbar : new sap.m.Toolbar({
                content : [ new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Participant List"
                }), new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer({}), new sap.m.Button("idPersonalizationButton", {
                    icon : "sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                }) ]
            }),
            columns : [ 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Firstname"
                })
                }), 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Lastname"
                })
                }), 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Job"
                })
                }), 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Company"
                })
                })
                ]
        });




        var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        var model = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
        var aData = model.getProperty("/courses");


        oModel1.setData({

            modelData : aData

        });

        oTable.setModel(oModel1);

        oTable.bindItems("/modelData/0/participant", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells : [ new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{firstname}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{lastname}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{job}",
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{company}",
            }),]
        }));


        var oIconTabBar = new sap.m.IconTabBar({

            items: [


                    new sap.m.IconTabFilter({

                        text: "General",
                        icon: "sap-icon://hint",
                        content: [




                                  ]



                    }),


                    new sap.m.IconTabFilter({

                        text: "Participants",
                        icon: "sap-icon://visits",
                        content: [
                                    oTable

                                  ]


                    }),

                    ]


        });



        return this.page = new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Course Details",
            content: [

                      oHeader, oIconTabBar

            ]
        });

    }

});
```

This is my "Details.controller"

```
sap.ui.controller("tem_trainer.Details", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Details
*/
//  onInit: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
* (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Details
*/
//  onBeforeRendering: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
* This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Details
*/
//  onAfterRendering: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Details
*/
//  onExit: function() {
//
//  }


    onBeforeFirstShow: function(oEvent){    

    if(oEvent.data.bindingContext){
        // Binding Kontext setzen
        this.getView().page.setBindingContext(oEvent.data.bindingContext);
    }

    },

    onListSelect: function(oEvent){  


        var oBindingContext = oEvent.getParameter(
                "listItem").getBindingContext();

        var sViewId = "detailCourse_" +
                      oEvent.getParameter(
                      "listItem").data("req_id");

        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
            "nav", 
            "to", {
            viewName: "tem_trainer.Details",
            viewId: sViewId,
            data: {
                bindingContext: oBindingContext
            }
        });
    },

    onListItemTap: function(oEvent){


        var oBindingContext = oEvent.oSource.getBindingContext();

        var sViewId = "detailCourse_" +
                      oEvent.oSource.data("req_id");

        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
            "nav", 
            "to", {
            viewName: "tem_trainer.Details",
            viewId: sViewId,
            data: {
                bindingContext: oBindingContext
            }
        });
    },

    onNavButtonTap: function(){
        // Wird ausgeführt wenn die  Hardwaretaste
        // oder der Back-Button gedrückt wird
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
                "nav", "back");
    }





});
```

This is my "Courses.json"

```
{
 "courses": [

  {
   "req_id": "1",
   "name" : "ABAP OO Basics",
   "start" : "20-08-2014",
   "end" : "22-08-2014",
   "starttime": "10:00:00",
   "endtime": "16:00:00",
   "status": "Booked",
   "room": "Room CDE",
   "adress" : "Adress No.1",
   "street": "Street No.1",
   "zip_code": "74892142578485",
   "city": "City No.1",
   "country": "Country No.1",
   "phone": "0595726764675435497436497",
   "fax":"12",
   "cap_min": "10",
   "cap_opt": "20",
   "cap_max": "30",
   "img": "./res/1.jpg",
   "content": "Test", 
   "participant":  [{   "firstname": "Maik",
                        "lastname": "Maier",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "muster" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Marco",
                        "lastname": "Schmidt",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "schmitt" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Hans",
                        "lastname": "Mueller",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "muster" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Matthias",
                        "lastname": "Gottlieb",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "schmitt" 
                    }]

  },
  {
   "req_id": "2",
   "name" : "ABAP OO Basics II",
   "start" : "22-08-2014",
   "end" : "23-08-2014",
   "starttime": "11:00:00",
   "endtime": "14:00:00",
   "status": "Booked",
   "room": "Room XYZ",
   "adress" : "Adress No.2",
   "street": "Street No.2",
   "zip_code": "2222",
   "city": "City No.2",
   "country": "Country No.2",
   "phone": "22222",
   "fax":"2222",
   "cap_min": "10",
   "cap_opt": "20",
   "cap_max": "30",
   "img": "./res/2.jpg",
   "content": "Test", 
   "participant":  [{   "firstname": "Name",
                        "lastname": "Name",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "muster" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Name2",
                        "lastname": "Name2",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "schmitt" 
                    }]

  }



 ]
}
```

EDIT: Here is my "Master.controller"

```
sap.ui.controller("tem_trainer.Master", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Master
*/
//  onInit: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
* (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Master
*/





    onBeforeRendering: function() {

        var oInbox = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inboxList");

        oInbox.removeSelections();

        var oJSONDataModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oJSONDataModel.loadData("./json/Courses.json");
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJSONDataModel);



    },

/**
* Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
* This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Master
*/
//  onAfterRendering: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
* @memberOf tem_trainer.Master
*/
//  onExit: function() {
//
//  }


    onBeforeFirstShow: function(oEvent) {


        this.bindListData();

        if(oEvent.data.title) {

            this.getView().page.setTitle(oEvent.data.title);


        }



    },


    bindListData: function(aFilters){

        var that = this;
        this.getView().oList.bindAggregation("items", {
          path: "/courses",
          factory: function(sId){
            return new sap.m.StandardListItem(sId, {
                icon : "sap-icon://course-program",
                title: {
                    path:"name", 
                },
                description: {
                    path:"start", 

                },
                type: jQuery.device.is.phone? 
                      sap.m.ListType.Navigation : sap.m.ListType.None,
                customData: [
                                new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
                                    key: "req_id",
                                    value: "{req_id}"
                                }),
                            ],
                tap: [that.onListItemTap, that]
            }).setInfoState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Success);
            },
            filters: aFilters
        });
    },

    onListSelect: function(oEvent){

        var oBindingContext = 
            oEvent.getParameter(
                "listItem"
                ).getBindingContext(),

            sViewId = "detailCourse_" + 
                       oEvent.getParameter(
                       "listItem").data("req_id");

        // Ereignis an EventBus übergeben
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
            "nav", 
            "to", {
              viewName: "tem_trainer.Details",
              viewId: sViewId,
              data: {
                 bindingContext: oBindingContext
            }
        });
    },

    onListItemTap: function(oEvent){
        // siehe onListSelect
        var oBindingContext = 
            oEvent.oSource.getBindingContext(),

        sViewId = "detailCourse_" + 
                   oEvent.oSource.data("req_id");

        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
            "nav", 
            "to", {
              viewName: "tem_trainer.Details",
              viewId: sViewId,
              data: {
                 bindingContext: oBindingContext
            }
        });
    },

    //Navigation Zurück
    onNavButtonTap: function(){
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
                "nav", 
                "back"
                );
        },      


    //Search Functionality

    handleSearch: function(oEvent) {

        this._updateList();


    },

    _updateList : function () {

        var filters = [];
        //var oView = this.getView();

        // Filter für die Suche
        //var searchString = oView.byId("searchField").getValue();
        var searchString = sap.ui.getCore().byId("searchField").getValue();
        if (searchString && searchString.length > 0) {
            var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, searchString);
            filters.push(filter);
        }

        // List Binding updaten
        //var list = oView.byId("inboxList");
        var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inboxList");
        var binding = list.getBinding("items");
        binding.filter(filters);

    },

});
```

EDIT: This is what i adjusted:

Details.controller

```
onInit : function() {

    var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    bus.subscribe("nav", "to", this.navToHandler, this);
},

navToHandler : function(channelId, eventId, data) {
    if (data && data.viewId) {
        var oBindingContext =  data.data.bindingContext;
        this.getView().setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
    } 
},  
//This is a function i already had and which is called by the view
onBeforeFirstShow: function(oEvent){    

if(oEvent.data.bindingContext){
    // Binding Kontext setzen
    this.getView().page.setBindingContext(oEvent.data.bindingContext);
}

},
```

In my Details.view

```
var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        var model = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
        var aData = model.getProperty("/courses");


        oModel1.setData({

            modelData : aData

        });

        oTable.setModel(oModel1);

        oTable.bindItems("participant", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells : [ new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{firstname}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{lastname}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{job}",
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{company}",
            }),]
        }));
```

Comment: Could you please show the master controller? Where do you subscribe to the event bus  ?

Comment: Hi Allen, i edited my initial post. Master controller is at the bottom now.

Comment: With this amount of code, I'd suggest you create a gist or jsbin to give folks a better chance of helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is similar to the demo app of [Approve Purchase Orders](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/poa/index.html).

See the json string:

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test/resources/sap/m/demokit/poa/model/mock.json

- Courses **1 : n** Course **1 : n** Participants
- PurchaseOrderCollection **1 : n** PurchaseOrder **1 :n** PurchaseOrder_Items

[image: Purchase Order demo]

You already did publish eventbus in your master controller when use selects the list item in the master view:

```
onListSelect: function(oEvent){

    var oBindingContext = 
        oEvent.getParameter(
            "listItem"
            ).getBindingContext(),

        sViewId = "detailCourse_" + 
                   oEvent.getParameter(
                   "listItem").data("req_id");

    // Ereignis an EventBus übergeben
    sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish(
        "nav", 
        "to", {
          viewName: "tem_trainer.Details",
          viewId: sViewId,
          data: {
             bindingContext: oBindingContext
        }
    });
},
```

You need to subscribe the eventbus in your Detail view controller to get the Binding Context of your list item and set the binding context for your detail view, in your case the single course.

```
onInit : function() {

    var bus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
    bus.subscribe("nav", "to", this.navToHandler, this);
},

navToHandler : function(channelId, eventId, data) {
    if (data && data.viewId) {
        var oBindingContext =  data.data.bindingContext;
        this.getView().setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
    } 
},
```

And adjust your binding paths of the table in the detail view, do not hard code 0.

```
 oTable.bindItems("participant", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells : [ new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{firstname}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{lastname}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{job}",
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{company}",
        }),]
    }));
```

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for your answer, unfortunately i did not get it work. I attached my adjustments at the bottom of my first post. I hope this is right.

Comment: It should work, you need to check the demo app and read my explanation about your requirements, data binding and Master-Detail app.  Are you able to post your code to JSBin that i can look into?

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your help, i could only send a mail or share a dropbox link. What do you prefer?

Comment: Just share a dropbox link

Comment: Hi, here is the dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vrqtokhju6q6r9o/AAAT63fFE9DUV1iQ58PxkGGJa?dl=0

Comment: Hi Andreas, i just fixed your code, please remove all the setModel code of oTable,oTable2 and oTable3 from your Details.view.js as the data binding context is set in the navToHandler method of Details.controller.js.

Comment: Hi Allen,thanks a lot. Only some lines of code to change ;) Thanks, saved my day :)